# Convert C-Style String to an Integer Array

Tags: c++

I have 2 functions, they are called `SplitInt(unsigned int x)` and `SplitChar(char x[])`

`SplitInt` takes in any positive integer, such as `12345`, and puts each digit into an integer array, but backwards. So for `SplitInt(12345)` the array would look like this:

```
array[0] = 5
array[1] = 4
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 2
array[4] = 1
```

`SplitChar()` is supposed to do the same thing but take in a C-Style string, such as `"12345"`.

How would I separate the individual digits and send them into an integer array? I am not allowed to use `string` class.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, remember that a c-style string is just a `char` array and that `1 = '1' - '0'`

Comment: Nothing to be honest. I only understand how to do it with integers being passed in because I just used modulus to separate the number to individual digits. For the string, I know conceptually what I wanna do. "123456789" gets passed in, I look at the first character, send it into the array, then second character, send it into array, and so on. Don't know the syntax to get that done though.

Comment: Is my function declaration correct? What I want to be able to do is this:
    SplitChar("123456789");

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MAX_STR_LENGTH 100

int array[MAX_STR_LENGTH];

int SplitChar(char x[])
{
    int len = strlen( x );

    if ( len > MAX_STR_LENGTH )
        return -1;

    int i = 0;

    while ( i < len )
    {
        array[len-i-1] = x[i] - '0';
        i++;
    }

    return len;
}
```

Returns the length of the string or -1 if too long.

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks, fixed

Comment: If you're going to provide free code, at least make it behave better than triggering UB when the input is too big...